# Directive custom two way binding with filter

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to make a custom directive that receives a parameter and has persistence in time, my problem is that I do not know how to apply a filter when sending the parameter in the view.
It should be something like that.

```
<ngbd-datepicker-popup 
                    [(fecha)]="contabilidad.feContabilizacion.dsFecha | toDateObject"
                    >
                </ngbd-datepicker-popup>
```

But the browser throws me the following into console

```
Parser Error: Cannot have a pipe in an action expression at column 43 in [(contabilidad.feContabilizacion.dsFecha | toDateObject)=$event] in ng:///AppModule/ContabilidadComponent.html@11:6 ("
                {{contabilidad.feContabilizacion.dsFecha}}
                <ngbd-datepicker-popup 
                    [ERROR ->][(fecha)]="(contabilidad.feContabilizacion.dsFecha | toDateObject)"
                    >
                </ngbd-datepicker-"): ng:///AppModule/ContabilidadComponent.html@11:6
```

Someone can lend me a hand, thanks.

Comment: When do you need the filter to be applied? (setting/getting value?). Can't you do it programmatically in the component code?

Comment: agree same.  create the pipe programmatically in your component.

Comment: @nipuna777 I need to apply the filter when reading and writing

Comment: In my component I have this to instantiate my calendar component

`<ngbd-datepicker-popup 
      [(fecha)]="contabilidad.feContabilizacion.dsFecha | toDateObject"
      >
     </ngbd-datepicker-popup>`

Comment: This is the component of my calendar

`@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-datepicker-popup',
  templateUrl: './calendario.datepicker.popup.html'
})`

Comment: `export class NgbdDatepickerPopup{
  @Input() disable:boolean;
  @Output() fechaChange = new EventEmitter();
  utilidates:Utilidades = new Utilidades();
  model={};
  
  @Input()
  get fecha(){
    return this.utilidates.getObjetDateToString(this.model);
  }

  set fecha(val:any){
    this.model = val;
    this.fechaChange.emit( this.model );
  }
}`

Comment: In the calendar component view, you reflect changes by adding
`[(ngModel)]="fecha"`